# How to efficiently calculate the numbers in a range of digits for an exponential function

Tags: c++, c, math, computer-science

I have an exponential function x^n where x is a number between 0-1 and n is a large integer(usually >100). Suppose there is no rounding error for x and n when represented by the double-precision number. How can I efficiently calculate the numbers in a range of digits for x^n? For example, I only want to get the numbers in the two thousand and first decimal places for 0.123^1000.

I know a high precision library like MPFR can perfectly do this job, but it is significantly slower than the double-precision computation. Since I do not need all the numbers in a number, I am looking for a more efficient way to do this, but I have no idea about it. Any suggestions or hints will be appreciated.

====================update1====================

Thanks for all your guys' comments and answers, I noticed that the example in the question might be not appropriate because the number is still not small enough to cause truncation, so I change it to 0.123^1000.

For those who prefer to see some real code, I made a reproducible example in R

```
x <- 0.123^1000
sprintf("%.10e",x)
y <- mpfr(0.123,precBits = 10000)^1000
y
```

x is a double-precision number and the result is 0, y is a 10000bits-precision number and can actually show the number of the result in the 2001st decimal digit. Note that the first few(maybe a lot) significant digits are usually not of interest, that is, if the true answer of an exponential function is 0.123 + 4 * 10^10000, I would be interested in that "4", instead of any numbers in 1,2,3. That is why a high-precision library may not be appropriate here for it will do a lot of unnecessary calculations.

Comment: Can you show the program you've already written, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results? You have to show your work first; it must meet all requirements for a [mre]; and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your program and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. We don't write entire programs for other people, here. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: Not really programming question.  Maybe ask on Math.  Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula for ideas.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The question is sufficiently stated. Minimal reproducible examples are primarily for questions asking for debugging help, and this is not such a question. Please do not apply inappropriate criteria to questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - my comment was appropriate. I count ten words in "It must meet all requirements for a [mre]", and there were a couple more words included in addition to those. Just a couple. My usual response to an insufficient debugging help type of a question, that focuses on its insufficient code example, is something completely different.

Comment: What is wrong with pow (0.123, 100)? Not just a rhetorical question; if you answer this then we have a much better idea what you actually need.

Comment: @gnasher729 It is not exact.

Comment: Do you want the most accurate answer? I mean, as if the number were truncated at the end of the range? Because a rounding at some point can change the digits. And, what do you mean by the range of digits? Counted from the first significant digit? Or the number is always less than one, and in this case, do you mean by counting from the decimal point? What is your use case?

Comment: @walnut: 0.123 is not exact to start with. You said "Suppose there is no rounding error for x". Something like 0.125 which _is_ exact takes 3 decimals. 0.125^10 takes 300 decimals.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am not the OP, but OP is saying that his particular initial value is assumed to be exactly representable. If `0.123` is not, then I guess that was just an unfortunate choice for demonstration.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Word count has nothing to do with whether your comment was appropriate. Stating that the question “must” meet all the requirements for a minimal reproducible example is false. There is nothing to reproduce because the question is not asking for help with an existing program. It asks for ideas. That is within the bounds of Stack Overflow; some questions are about theory or methods, not debugging or constructing specific programs. This is one such, and there is no reason a minimal reproducible example should be provided.

Comment: Thanks for @SamVarshavchik and other guys' comments(I cannot refer you in one comment), I may choose a bad example, 0.123^100 is not small enough to cause any problem, I have changed it to 0.123^1000. A reproducible example is also attached

Answer (score 1):

You need a library for calculations with **large integers**. You can implement [rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) with this library and corresponding calculations. Then it's easy to obtain any decimal digit of a rational number. Look at the code example in Python.

If you are interested in the decimal digit `d` of a rational number `f`, you calculate `f * 10^d`, use only its integer part and take only the least significant digit.

```py
import fractions

def get_digit(f, d):
    f1 = f * 10**d
    return (f1.numerator // f1.denominator) % 10

f = fractions.Fraction(123, 1000)
p = f ** 100

assert get_digit(p, 91) == 0
assert get_digit(p, 92) == 9
assert get_digit(p, 93) == 7
assert get_digit(p, 94) == 8
assert get_digit(p, 95) == 3
assert get_digit(p, 96) == 8
```

Update:

The n-th decimal digit is affected by all less significant decimal digits during calculations. For this reason it is impossible to calculate the n-th decimal digit *directly*. And the number of necessary significant digits make the *double precision data type* useless. For this reason the calculation on **large integers** is a reasonable practical compromise.

Comment: Sorry for wrong syntax highlighting. The `//` is a valid operator in Python, not a comment delimiter.

Comment: I fixed the syntax highlighting. OP is saying in the question that using high-precision libraries takes too much time and this will then be the same for rational number libraries as well. They are asking whether there is a shortcut that doesn't require calculating the whole number and may therefore be faster.

Comment: @walnut Since the n-th decimal digit is affected by all less significant digits during calculation, there is no escape, you cannot calculate the selected decimal digit directly. I wanted to demonstrate that it's unnecessary to work with floating point numbers, large integers suffice. In fact, I use rational numbers only for brevity, the implementation can be reduced to integers.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that calculating the whole decimal expansion (or the numerator/denominator exactly) must be as costly as calculating part of the decimal expansion. But if that is your point, I think you should make it clear in the answer. The question itself seems to be a rather non-trivial math problem.

Comment: @walnut The OP's example 0.123^100 has 209 significant digits, the most significant one is located at 92nd decimal position. The OP is interested in decimal positions 101, 102 etc. so almost whole result have to be calculated anyway. It's definitely an interesting mathematical problem.